# How to generate a video file on a browser

Tags: javascript, video, video-capture, video-processing, screen-capture

I'm working on a project with kinetic typography where the user can write something and download it on a video format but I'm having trouble generating the (video) file.

I thought of screen capturing but most browsers are blocking those features due to security concerns (and I wanted to add audio later on).

I've looked into https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-capture/ but its documentation doesn't say much nor gives examples.

I've seen https://mgechev.github.io/jscapture/ but it only works with versions bellow Chrome 37.

I've seen https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js but it only records canvases and I'm working with text.

How can I generate a video client-side (preferably) on a browser?

Comment: Why not have the text be saved on a canvas then record that ccapcture?

Comment: @AldoSanchez because you can't have text on a canvas, you can just draw text. Do you know a way of inserting text on a canvas like <span> hello </span>?

Comment: maybe something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp I'm not super experienced with canvas, but I would probably start there.

Comment: @AldoSanchez that's what I was saying. That draws text on the canvas. I want text that i can select and manipulate.